# Why does a part of this variable get replaced when combining it with a string?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following Bash script which loops through the lines of a file:

```
INFO_FILE=playlist-info-test.txt
line_count=$(wc -l $INFO_FILE | awk '{print $1}')

for ((i=1; i<=$line_count; i++))
do
    current_line=$(sed "${i}q;d" $INFO_FILE)

    CURRENT_PLAYLIST_ORIG="$current_line"
    input_file="$CURRENT_PLAYLIST_ORIG.mp3"
    echo $input_file
done
```

This is a sample of the playlist-info-test.txt file:

```
Playlist 1
Playlist2
Playlist 3
```

The output of the script should be as follows:

```
Playlist 1.mp3
Playlist2.mp3
Playlist 3.mp3
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
.mp3list 1
.mp3list2
.mp3list 3
```

I have spent a few hours on this and can't understand why the ".mp3" part is being moved to the front of the string. I initially thought it was because of the space in the lines of the input file, but removing the space doesn't make a difference. I also tried using a while loop with `read line` and the input file redirected into it, but that does not make any difference either.

Comment: As an aside, starting a copy of `sed` every time you want to read a single line is a **really** inefficient way to read a file in bash. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for some saner alternatives.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Yea I am aware. However, my actual script (the one in the question is a simplified version) requires me to loop through all the lines, and for each line, also read the next line. I didn't know how I could achieve this using the while loop + file redirection method. You can find the whole script [here](https://github.com/Probotect0r/scripts/blob/master/playlist-splitter/splitMp3.sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the `playlist-info-test.txt` contents and the script, and get the output you expected. Most likely there are non-printable characters in your `playlist-info-test.txt` or script which are messing up the processing. Check the binary contents of both files using for example `xxd -g 1` and look for non-newline (`0a`) non-printing characters.

Comment: This was it! I manually made a file and wrote in the three lines and it worked perfectly. I inspected the orignal file with xxd and found out there were CR (`0d`)characters at the end of each line, right before the LF character, which would explain why the rest of the string was being moved to the front of the line.

Comment: @SagarDesai: or use `cat -A file` to find special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Did the file come from Windows? DOS and Windows end their lines with carriage return (hex 0d, sometimes represented as `\r`) followed by linefeed (hex 0a, sometimes represented as `\n`). Unix just uses linefeed, and so tends to treat the carriage return as part of the content of the line. In your case, it winds up at the end of the `current_line` variable, so `input_file` winds up something like "Playlist 1\r.mp3". When you print this to the terminal, the carriage return makes it go back to the beginning of the line (that's what carriage return means), so it prints as:

```
Playlist 1
.mp3
```

...with the ".mp3" printed over the "Play" part, rather than on the next line like I have it above.

Solution: either fix the file (there's a fairly standard `dos2unix` program that does precisely this), or change your script to strip carriage returns as it reads the file. Actually, I'd recommend a rewrite anyway, since your current use of `sed` to pick out lines is rather weird and inefficient. In a shell script, the standard way to read through a file line-by-line is to use a loop like `while read  -r current_line; do [commands here]; done <"$INFO_FILE"`. There's a possible problem that if any commands inside the loop read from standard input, they'll wind up inhaling part of that file; you can fix that by passing the file over unit 3 rather than standard input. With that fix and a trick to trim carriage returns, here's what it looks like:

```
INFO_FILE=playlist-info-test.txt

while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r current_line <&3; do
    CURRENT_PLAYLIST_ORIG="$current_line"
    input_file="$CURRENT_PLAYLIST_ORIG.mp3"
    echo "$input_file"
done 3<"$INFO_FILE"
```

(The carriage return trim is done by `read` -- it always auto-trims leading and trailing whitespace, and setting `IFS` to `$' \t\n\r'` tells it to treat spaces, tabs, linefeeds, and carriage returns as whitespace. And since that assignment is a prefix to the `read` command, it applies only to that one command and you don't have to set `IFS` back to normal afterward.)

A couple of other recommendations while I'm here: double-quote all variable references (as I did with `echo "$input_file"` above), and avoid all-caps variable names (there are a bunch with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those it can have weird effects). Oh, and try passing your scripts to [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it's good at spotting common mistakes.

Comment: Yup! The file was taken from a drive which is shared with a Windows install. I reached the same conclusion once I inspected the file with xdd and saw the 0d before the 0a. Thanks for the suggestion on the loop, but I had to do it this way for a reason. The script in my question is a simplified version of a larger script in which I also need to read the next line after the current line in each iteration of the loop. You can find the whole script on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Probotect0r/scripts/blob/master/playlist-splitter/splitMp3.sh). And I did end up running dos2unix to fix the issue.

Comment: @SagarDesai Ah, that makes more sense then. BTW, you can still \r-proof the script by using `current_line=$(sed "${i}q;d" $INFO_FILE | tr -d '\r')`.